# How to invoke desktop site of the Facebook Page on mobile devices?

Tags: android, iphone, html, facebook, mobile

Here is a sample Facebook page (Ford Mustang!).
http://www.facebook.com/fordmustang

When I invoke this URL on Android browser, it leads to mobile designed page.
(m.facebook.com/fordmustang)

But, in this page, I can't access any Facebook apps in Ford Mustang page such as,
http://www.facebook.com/fordmustang?sk=app_53267368995
and I can only access wall, info and photo via Android browser.

Therefore, Id like to invoke the Mustang page as desktop site (full PC size screen)
from my html.

At this moment, following code leads to mobile site.
`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/fordmustang">Ford Mustang desktop site</a>`
And also following code can't work the app. (leads to wall)
`<a href="http://www.facebook.com/fordmustang?sk=app_53267368995">Mustang Twitter</a>`

Please let me know if you know any good way to do this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try changing the User agent string that is reported to the site. See [Here](http://lifehacker.com/5547037/change-the-user-agent-on-an-android-phone)

Comment: No, I'd like to know the URL(a href="xxx") to access desktop site.   And the HTML code with the URL will be created by my PHP programs.

Comment: This question is still open and need your help. Thanks!

Comment: @MaryJJ FrisbeeBen's answer was perfectly good. There's no special URL for accessing the desktop site that I'm aware of, so spoofing your user-agent is probably the best way to go about it.